# Java on PATH is ignored (Ubuntu/Bash)

Tags: java, bash, ubuntu

In Ubuntu I have added the following to my `~/.bashrc`

```sh
export JAVA_HOME=/home/user/tools/jdk-11.0.4
export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin
export PATH=/home/user/tools/apache-maven-3.6.1/bin:$PATH
```

But when I run (after a reboot):

```sh
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~19.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

Why is it still picking up java 8 from `/usr/bin/java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locations in the `PATH` environment variable are searched in order, and the first match for an executable is returned. Since you added `JAVA_HOME` at the end of the `PATH`, the global version of `java` is found first (as `/usr/bin` comes before `JAVA_HOME`).

Try this order instead (in the second line of your code above):

```
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
```

BTW, it is not necessary to reboot each time you change `~/.bashrc`. You can just open a new shell terminal.